# TypeError: 'rest_framework.request.Request' object is not compatible with 'django.http.HttpRequest' in Django API view

Tags: python, django

I'm working on a Django API view where I need to handle a GET request and update some configurations to disk. However, when I execute the view, I encounter the following error:

```
The `request` argument must be an instance of `django.http.HttpRequest`, not `rest_framework.request.Request`.
```

Here is a snippet of my source code:

```py
@api_view(["GET"])
def applyAllConfigChangesToDisk(request):
    logging.debug("")
    try:
        result = False
        response = {}
        for configControl in configControlObjs:
            result = configControlObjs[configControl].SaveToFile()
            if result:
                response = {
                    "status": "success",
                    "message": f"Successfully Updated all changes to disk!",
                }
            else:
                response = {
                    "status": "error",
                    "message": f"Sorry! Unable to updated all changes to disk.",
                }
        return Response(response)
    except Exception as e:
        response = {
            "status": "error",
            "message": f"Sorry! Unable to update data: {e}",
        }
        return Response(response)
```

The error is specifically pointing to the `applyAllConfigChangesToDisk` function and mentions that the `request` argument must be an instance of `django.http.HttpRequest`, not `rest_framework.request.Request`.

I am using Django with the Django REST Framework. How can I resolve this error and ensure that the `request` object is of the correct type (`django.http.HttpRequest`)?

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!